# Protect drone from lightning

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, dielectric, lightning

I am designing a dirigible, robotic drone. It is basically a polyurethane airship, approx 3.6 m length and 2.1 m diameter.

I am worried about lightnings: as far as I know, a Faraday Cage should be able to protect its interior from external electrostatic fields. Now my question is: a lightning is much more likely to strike on a conductive material mid-air rather than on its surroundings, right? Now, even if the Faraday Cage could protect it from the electrostatic field, there should be a huge amount of energy released in the Faraday Cage due to the Joule effect of the lightning streaming through it, enough energy to melt the structure.

So I was wondering: is there any other strategy to protect the drone? On example, could it be possible to cover it with some dielectric (is there anything stronger than air?) so that lightning would rather strike somewhere else?

Comment: Asking for specific design recommendations may fall afoul of our [engineering policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site). In any event, it might be better to ask a more fundamental question of "will my airship be more likely to be struck by lightning, and will that lightning damage it?" After all, airplanes certainly aren't often destroyed or melted by an errant bolt of lightning...

Answer (score 1):

If the majority of the drone is a "gasbag", you may want to install a fairly heavy-gauge wire running from the top to the bottom to act as a sort of lightning rod.  The sensitive electronics should be fine if they are within a Faraday Cage.  As long as the lightning has an easy path to take through your aircraft, it shouldn't damage anything else.  That being said, flying a drone in a thunderstorm is not generally a good idea and should be avoided if possible.